# How do I change update a value within a column in R?

Tags: r, data-science

I need to update a value within a column in R. How do I do this?

name of data: Data
name of column: Residence

```
Data$Residence

Residence
1.Co-op
2.Co-op
3.Co-op
4.Condo
5.Condo
6.Condo
7.House
8.House
```

If I wanted to change the name of #4 or # 8, how would I do this?

Comment: You can do `Data$Residence[c(4, 8)] <- c('newvalue1', 'newvalue2')`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately I'm running into this error message." invalid factor level, NA generated "

Comment: @JimmyCrane - you have a `factor` column. Try converting like `Data$Residence <- as.character(Data$Residence)` first, then try akrun's code again.

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution

```
datamy<-read.table(text= "Residence
    1.Co-op
    2.Co-op
    3.Co-op
    4.Condo
    5.Condo
    6.Condo
    7.House
    8.House", header = T)
    datamy$Residence <- as.character(datamy$Residence)

    datamy$Residence[(datamy$Residence) =="4.Condo" ]<-"condo"
```